# Writing Ruby File with Only \n line breaks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have recently moved an application from Ubuntu across to a Redhat server, and noticed that a difference has occurred when writing a file, with \r\n being written, rather than simply \n.

I am explicitly setting the \n in the data to be written. So, for example

```
data = "Hello\nWorld"
File.open("#{ Rails.root }/tmp/file.txt", "wb") { |f| f.write(data) }
```

What is being written is actually "Hello\r\nWorld".

I know Ruby sets the line breaks according to the system it is being run on, but is there a way of enforcing it to keep to \n whatever the system?

Answer (score -1):

Don't put escape sequences in double quote because ruby look for substitutions and replace them with some binary value.

If you want enforcing ruby to keep to same like '\n' than you have to use single quote.

Example:

data = 'Hello\nWorld'

File.open("#{ Rails.root }/tmp/file.txt", "wb") { |f| f.write(data) }

It will keep it same. :)